# Cannot install or start npm for react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Following error is been thrown when tried to install react.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\web\desktop\boy\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\web\desktop\boy\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\web\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-15T12_19_50_959Z-debug.log




 npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\web\desktop                                                                                                                \boy\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\web\desktop\bo                                                                                                                y\package.json'
npm WARN boy No description
npm WARN boy No repository field.
npm WARN boy No README data
npm WARN boy No license field
```

Answer (score 3):

When you type

```
npm run start
```

**npm** tries to find *start* in the scripts section of your **package.json** file.

***As you don't have such file, npm fails with ENOENT***, which is an abbreviation for Error NO ENTry.

Cheers.

Comment: Create a package.json by typing `npm init` and completing the process. Then try install again.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue but in the end, find out that the project is within another folder at the same place.
Demo project > My Project (containing node modules and files)
I was in the Demo project and trying to right npm start.